# What are the differences between URL, URI and URN?

Tags: contracturi

I encountered these words over and over again. But I'm not sure what the differences are? It is different from the IP address right? Can you please explain the difference for me? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I give you an analogy. URL is Uniform Resource Locator, which is like a physical mail address to your home. URI is Uniform Resource Identifier, which is a string that identifies a resource. This is like identifying whether your home is a single family home, condo, townhouse, or apartment, along with any other specifications that allow people to recognize what type of home you have. URN is Uniform Resource Name, which is used to identify resources in a permanent way, even after that resource does not exist anymore. This is like the city’s record of who’s the previous owner of your home before, even if the previous owner no longer live there anymore.